# Set a variable from extended variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have an extended array and I want to transfer values from it to a normal variable.

from this:

```
!a[i]!=value
```

I want to get:

```
%comm%=value
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You need to include sufficient content from your batch file to allow us to see and if necessary replicate your environment. You can do that by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50278672/edit) and formatting that code using the `{}` button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you are asking, see this based on your  examples

```
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) Do @Set "a[%%i]=Var%%i"
Set a[
```

:: Will return

```
a[1]=Var1
a[2]=Var2
a[3]=Var3
a[4]=Var4
a[5]=Var5
```

:: If you then set

```
Set i=3
Set !a[%i%]!=value
```

:: This will set the variable referenced by `%a[3]%` to `value`

```
set Var
```

:: returns

```
Var3=value
```

---

Also your second command will indirectly set the var referenced by `%comm%` to `value`

```
Set comm=Var1
Set %comm%=value
Set %comm%
```

:: returns

```
Var1=value
```